# Remove extra blank characters in a string

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to keep only one blank characters in a string. Below shows the sample.

```
"today  is a nice day"                       == > "today is a nice day"

"today     is      a nice day"               == > "today is a nice day"

"today  is    a nice       day"              == > "today is a nice day"

"today       is  a       nice day         "  == > "today is a nice day"
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way which worked for me is

Right Click on field --> Format Field --> Paragraph

Change Text Interpretation to HTML Text and click OK.